# Passing a socket connection to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I have a react app which uses socket.io and in my app I have two routes (react-router-dom). Login page and a Chat page.

In my login page/component I need to define socket as `const socket =io();` so that I can submit the login form and socket.emit a join event. The user then gets redirected to the chat page.

In my chat page I also need to access socket for various methods and events.

However I think I'm right in assuming that defining `const socket = io();` twice would make another connection? Is there a way I can pass the socket connection from the login page to the chat page?

---

For clarity...

Login Component:

https://github.com/alienbuild/node-passthe40/blob/master/public/src/components/pages/Login.js

Chat Component:

https://github.com/alienbuild/node-passthe40/blob/master/public/src/components/pages/Chat.js

Comment: Ideally you have to use the state management like Redux or Flux but as I can see you have very few pages in your app , you can use the localstorage  in login page and store the socket object into localstoarage and in chat component access the socket object from localstorage insted of creating a new one.

Comment: @DhavalPatel thank you for the reply. That does makes sense, If I don't define what the socket var is in my login and chat component though, how can I use the methods I've defined?

Comment: you just need to define once in login page and store it into localstoreage then when you need a socket object you have to pull it back from storage.

Comment: @DhavalPatel thank you I think I understand. I see from the documentation io accepts a url and options. Would I just pass the object directly into io() as a url?

Comment: There is also one more soultion but it's not recommanded you can store the socket object in login component like window.socket=io(); and then you can use the same object in your chat component like const socket=window.socket;

Comment: You should also consider using React context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and passing socket that you create in App.js to context.

Similar approach would be HoC to share same socker (https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Lastly, you could create a plain js Singleton service (SocketManager) that creates a single socket (if it's not created yet) and then just request the socket inside Login and Chat components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `React Context` to share the socket object between your component like.

you need to create an context and export it.

```
import React from 'react'

const SocketContext = React.createContext()

export default SocketContext
```

and use it like

```
import React
import SocketContext from './socket-context'
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io()

const App = props => (
  <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
    <YourChildComponent />
  </SocketContext.Provider>
)

export default App
```

more info [Click Here](https://itnext.io/how-to-use-a-single-instance-of-socket-io-in-your-react-app-6a4465dcb398)